# GetElementById isn't working on certain boxes

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make an automatic login in my program.

**This is the code I'm using to find the email box and then set the value:**
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value,", ID & "@hotmail.com")

If I insect the element of the email box it says *input class="textbox" type="email" name="email"*

What am I doing wrong? :L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element doesn't necessarily have to have an ID.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname(v=vs.110).aspx

If that's the case, you should take a look at getting a collection via GetElementsByTagName and looping through - something along these lines:

```
Dim Elems As HtmlElementCollection 

Elems = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")

For Each elem As HtmlElement In Elems
   Dim nameValue As String = elem.GetAttribute("name")
      If nameValue.ToLower().Equals("email") Then 
          elem.SetAttribute("value,", ID & "@hotmail.com")
      End If 
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure what that code is supposed to do but I tried it and it didn't do anything. I changed the name and input and all those strings to "email" and it didn't do anything either. I'm quite new to VB.NET so I don't know much...

Answer (score 2):

Refer to id instead of name. i.e. "email_ema" instead of "email"

input name="email" type="button" id="email_ema" value="+" style="display:None;"...

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email_ema").SetAttribute("value,", ID & "@hotmail.com")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How do I find the ID of something though?